# about the existence-uniqueness theorem

Tags: real-analysis, ordinary-differential-equations

The theorem states the following:

For the initial value problem:$\frac{dy}{dx}=f(x,y),y(a)=b$, if f is continuous near (a,b),then at least one solution exists on some open interval $I$ containing $x=a$. If in addition, $\frac{\partial f}{\partial y}$ is continuous near (a,b), then the existed solution is unique on some open interval $J \subseteq I$.

What does it mean by "near (a,b)"?

If we let $\vec{a}=(a,b)$, does "near (a,b)" mean the set $B(\vec{a};r)$ or $B(\vec{a};r) \setminus \vec{a}$ ?

where $B(\vec{a};r)$ denotes an open ball centered at $\vec{a}$ with radius r for some $r>0$

For example, consider $\frac{dy}{dx}=\sqrt[3]{y},y(0)=0$.

$f(x,y)=\sqrt[3]{y}$ is continuous on $B(\vec{0};r) \setminus \vec{0}$ so there exists at least one solution on some open interval I containing the point a.

$\frac{\partial f}{\partial y}=\frac{1}{3} \cdot \frac{1}{\sqrt[3]{y^2}}$ is also continuous on $B(\vec{0};r) \setminus \vec{0}$, so there is a unique solution on some open interval $J \subseteq I$.

Then i checked the answer, it says existence is guaranteed but uniqueness is not guaranteed in any neighbourhood of x=0.

So i guess "near (a,b)" means the set $B(\vec{a};r)$ i.e we include the point (a,b)?

Comment: @user474330 , except p? then why the answer says the uniqueness is not guaranteed? the partial derivative with respect to y is clearly continuous at $x \neq 0$.

Answer (score 0):

$(a,b)$ should be included. Specifically the version of this theorem usually taught in undergrad ODEs says that if you have some closed rectangle with $(a,b)$ in its interior such that $f$ and $\frac{\partial f}{\partial y}$ are continuous on that rectangle, then the solution exists and is unique.